# Retrieving network mask in Python

Tags: python

How would one go about retrieving a network device's netmask (In Linux preferably, but if it's cross-platform then cool)? I know how in C on Linux but I can't find a way in Python -- minus ctypes perhaps. That or parsing ifconfig. Any other way?

```
ioctl(socknr, SIOCGIFNETMASK, &ifreq) // C version
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439094/) works for me in Python 2.2 on Linux:

```
iface = "eth0"
socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM), 35099, struct.pack('256s', iface))[20:24])
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hunting down the op value.

Comment: Does this work with an IPv6-only network?

Answer (score 9):

The [`netifaces`](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/) module deserves a mention here. Straight from the docs:

```
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo0', 'gif0', 'stf0', 'en0', 'en1', 'fw0']

>>> addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses('en0')
>>> addrs[netifaces.AF_INET]
[{'broadcast': '10.15.255.255', 'netmask': '255.240.0.0', 'addr': '10.0.1.4'}, {'broadcast': '192.168.0.255', 'addr': '192.168.0.47'}]
```

Works on Windows, Linux, OS X, and probably other UNIXes.

Comment: Thanks for that. Works great and easier that starting a subprocess like I was doing.

Answer (score 4):

Did you look here?

http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html

This works for me in python 2.5.2 on Linux. Was finishing it when Ben got ahead, but still here it goes (sad to waste the effort :-) ):

```
vinko@parrot:~$ more get_netmask.py
# get_netmask.py by Vinko Vrsalovic 2009
# Inspired by http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439093/
# and http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439094/
# Code: 0x891b SIOCGIFNETMASK

import socket
import fcntl
import struct
import sys

def get_netmask(ifname):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x891b, struct.pack('256
s',ifname))[20:24])

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        print get_netmask(sys.argv[1])
vinko@parrot:~$ python get_netmask.py lo
255.0.0.0
vinko@parrot:~$ python get_netmask.py eth0
255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Nope didn't see that one. Sweet. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the idea to rely on subprocess to use a simple ifconfig (Linux) or ipconfig (windows) request to retrieve the info (if the ip is known).
***Comments welcome*** :

WINDOWS

```
ip = '192.168.1.10' #Example
proc = subprocess.Popen('ipconfig',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if ip.encode() in line:
        break
mask = proc.stdout.readline().rstrip().split(b':')[-1].replace(b' ',b'').decode()
```

UNIX-Like

```
ip = '192.168.1.10' #Example
proc = subprocess.Popen('ifconfig',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if ip.encode() in line:
        break
mask = line.rstrip().split(b':')[-1].replace(b' ',b'').decode()
```

IP is retrieved using a socket connection to the web and using `getsockname()[0]`

Comment: `ifconfig` is not always pre-installed on linux anymore, the new command is `ip addr`

Comment: @Typewar, is ip addr pre-installed on old linux versions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library: http://github.com/rlisagor/pynetlinux. Note: I'm the author of the library.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows  this piece of code may be useful:

```
import os
import sys
import _winreg


def main():
    adapter_list_key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards')

    adapter_count = _winreg.QueryInfoKey(adapter_list_key)[0]

    for i in xrange(adapter_count):
        sub_key_name = _winreg.EnumKey(adapter_list_key, i)
        adapter_key = _winreg.OpenKey(adapter_list_key, sub_key_name)
        (adapter_service_name, _) = _winreg.QueryValueEx(adapter_key, "ServiceName")
        (description, _) = _winreg.QueryValueEx(adapter_key, "Description")

        adapter_registry_path = os.path.join(r'SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services',
            adapter_service_name, "Parameters", "Tcpip")
        adapter_service_key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            adapter_registry_path)
        (subnet_mask, _) = _winreg.QueryValueEx(adapter_service_key, "SubnetMask")
        (ip_address, _) = _winreg.QueryValueEx(adapter_service_key, "IpAddress")

        sys.stdout.write("Name: %s\n" % adapter_service_name)
        sys.stdout.write("Description: %s\n" % description)
        sys.stdout.write("SubnetMask: %s\n" % subnet_mask)
        sys.stdout.write("IpAdress: %s\n" % ip_address)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Get network adapters list from `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards` registry key and than extract more info about each adapter from `HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\{adapter_guid}\Parameters\Tcpip` key.

I test it on Windows XP with 2 virtual adapters, it works fine. Should work in 2000, 2003, and Vista too.

Comment: I added Py3 compat (no big deal) and DHCP (big deal for me). Also uses `CurrentControlSet`. I put a copy [here](http://www.revragnarok.com/blog/blog/IP_addr_python) because it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Answer using [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import psutil
import socket

def get_ipv4_netmask_from_nic(interface):
    interface_addrs = psutil.net_if_addrs().get(interface) or []
    for snicaddr in interface_addrs:
        if snicaddr.family == socket.AF_INET:
            return snicaddr.netmask
```

Example:

```
>>> get_ipv4_netmask_from_nic("eth0")
'255.255.255.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the python pyroute2 library you can get all network element attributes:

```
from pyroute2 import IPRoute
ip = IPRoute()
info = [{'iface': x['index'], 'addr': x.get_attr('IFA_ADDRESS'), 'mask':  x['prefixlen']} for x in ip.get_addr()]
```

More information available here:http://pyroute2.org/pyroute2-0.3.14p4/iproute.html

Answer (score 0):

I have an update on the original answer as the original code:

```py
struct.pack('256s', iface)
```

Throws an error in Python 3.9, so here is a revisited version:

```py
    SIOCGIFADDR = 0x8915

    def get_iface_ip(iface: str):
        """
        Get network interface IP using the network interface name
        :param iface: Interface name (like eth0, enp2s0, etc.)
        :return IP address in the form XX.XX.XX.XX
        """
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
            iface_bin = struct.pack('256s', bytes(iface, 'utf-8'))
            packet_ip = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), SIOCGIFADDR, iface_bin)[20:24]
        return socket.inet_ntoa(packet_ip)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) and [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

From the documentation

> **ipaddress** provides the capabilities to create, manipulate and operate on IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and networks.
>  The functions and classes in this module **make it straightforward to handle various tasks related to IP addresses** ...

```py
>>> import socket
>>> import ipaddress
>>>
>>> ip_addr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
>>> netmask = ipaddress.IPv4Network(ip_addr).netmask
>>> print(netmask)
255.255.255.255
>>> ...
```

This may question may be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867435/get-subnet-from-ip-address). It is not the same question,but also offers a solution to your question.

Comment: Are you sure, this is netmask ?

Comment: What do you mean?, netmask and [subnet mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) are the same

Comment: Hi @torswq! I said so because it gives '255.255.255.255' in every case. My netmask is '255.255.255.0' but it outputs '255.255.255.255'.

Comment: "From the documentation": https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network
"`If no mask is provided, it’s considered to be /32.`"
And `gethostbyname` never appends a subnet prefix length.
So you will always get `255.255.255.255`. Module `ipaddress` is a pure calculation library and does not lookup missing information from the system.

Comment: I will delete this question as it is not helpful and provides wrong information, sorry for the confusion