# Get network address and network mask in Python

Tags: python, sockets, ip, ip-address

In my Python script I need to retrieve both the IP address of the machine the script is running on and its network address and its network bytes.

As for the IP address, I found the solution in the archive:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("www.google.com",80))
myAddress = (s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```

But how should I go about finding network address and network bytes? I need to put this information into a filter for tcpdump in the format `$NetworkAddress/$NetworkBytes`, if that helps at all.

Example:

```
128.1.2.0/20
```

I can actually find it under `inet`  when I run `ip addr`.  Any easy way to get this information in Python?

Comment: NetworkBytes or network mask?

Comment: +1 for showing what you have so far

Comment: What do you mean by "network address" and "network bytes"?

Comment: OK, I added more details to my original post.

Comment: Your example seems to be an IP-address/prefix-length. I still have no idea what you mean by "NetworkBytes" because if that's supposed to mean the same thing as "prefix length" then NetworkBytes is a VERY odd name to call that... Anyway, if you do mean IP address/prefix length, then, do you mean the IP address and prefix length assigned to one of the local interfaces on the machine the script is running on?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Linux try

```
iface = "eth0"
socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM), 
                             35099, struct.pack('256s', iface))[20:24])
```

or  http://github.com/rlisagor/pynetlinux

(as suggested here: [Retrieving network mask in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936444/retrieving-network-mask-in-python))

For Linux, Windows and MacOS consider http://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/

**Update:**

If you need cidr (like '128.1.2.0/20'), you can use any of the related libs: http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=cidr&submit=search

For example `netaddr`:

```
>> from netaddr import IPNetwork
>> print str(IPNetwork('1.2.3.4/255.255.255.0').cidr)
1.2.3.0/24
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I need something in the form given in my question, that is "address/PrefixLength" instead of the actual network mask. Is there any fast way to do this?

Comment: Which OS are you interested in?

Comment: Thank you. I can't find package netstat. Could you please point it to me? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve any ip-related info with [pyroute2](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2) module:

```
from pyroute2 import IPDB
ip = IPDB()
print(ip.interfaces['em1'].ipaddr)
ip.release()
```

Or as a variant:

```
from pyroute2 import IPRoute
ip = IPRoute()
info = [{'iface': x['index'],
         'addr': x.get_attr('IFA_ADDRESS'),
         'mask': x['prefixlen']} for x in ip.get_addr()]
ip.close()
```