# Searching in a text and save in string, python

Tags: python, search

As a result of command ifconfig in Linux I just want to keep the int addr and Mask in two strings:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:33:0a:e9:15:76
          inet addr:10.244.21.118  Bcast:10.244.21.127  Mask:255.244.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::0050:aff:fee9:1576/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:807304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:611741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:253087331 (241.3 MiB)  TX bytes:167902811 (160.1 MiB)
```

to get finally this:

```
inet_addr: "10.244.21.118"
mask="255.244.255.192"
```

Is there any faster way? My only idea is parsing every line and then searching for int addr and deleting the name... but I don't know if it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import re

def give_string():
    string = '''
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:33:0a:e9:15:76
          inet addr:10.244.21.118  Bcast:10.244.21.127  Mask:255.244.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::0050:aff:fee9:1576/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:807304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:611741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:253087331 (241.3 MiB)  TX bytes:167902811 (160.1 MiB)
    '''
    return string

def main():
    string = give_string()
    regex = re.compile('^.*inet addr:\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) .*Mask:\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*$', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    match = regex.match(string)
    ip_address = match.group(1)
    subnet_mask=match.group(2)
    print(ip_address, subnet_mask)

main()
```

BTW, I usually say that people overuse regex's, but this is a pretty good case for one.

Answer (score 3):

3 general options in python:

- Parse it out of a shell call to `ifconfig`.  Your current approach, and the approach of all the other answers.
- Use sockets.  Set up a UDP socket to connect to an external host, look at its sockname and find its mask.  You will have to deal with some (very) low-level APIs.
- Use an external module.  e.g. [python-ifconfig](http://code.google.com/p/python-ifconfig/).

Here's the basic form of the second approach using sockets:

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #UDP

s.connect(('google.com',0)) #prepare UDP socket to connect to some external host

s.getsockname()
Out[17]: ('10.0.2.15', 56965)

socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s, 0x891b, struct.pack('256s', 'eth0'))[20:24])
Out[18]: '255.255.255.0'
```

Credit to answerers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936444/retrieving-network-mask-in-python) for the mask solution, I did not know those opcodes off the top of my head :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html), you can accomplish this. The code below places everything in a `devices` list, but the `for` loop.

```
import re

ifconfig = """eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:33:0a:e9:15:76
          inet addr:10.244.21.118  Bcast:10.244.21.127  Mask:255.244.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::0050:aff:fee9:1576/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:807304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:611741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:253087331 (241.3 MiB)  TX bytes:167902811 (160.1 MiB)
"""

devices = []      
for d in re.findall(r'^(\S+).*?inet addr:(\S+).*?Mask:(\S+)', ifconfig, re.S | re.M):
    devices.append((d[0], d[1], d[2]))

print devices
```

Outputs:

```
[('eth0', '10.244.21.118', '255.244.255.192')]
```

Finally, with a slight modification, you can have this loop through each device that appears when you run `ifconfig`. You would need one more `for` loop before the `re.findall` loop, to split it by device. I believe something like `for dev in ifconfig.split('\n\n'):` would properly split it by device.

Answer (score 1):

Since ifconfig's output is predictable, regular expressions are not really needed.  This code captures the output and parses just using the usual python string facilities:

```
from subprocess import check_output
lines = check_output(["/sbin/ifconfig", "eth0"]).split('\n')
line = lines[1] # Get the 2nd line
parts = line.split()
inet_addr = parts[2]
mask = parts[-1].split(':')[1]
print 'inet_addr=%s mask=%s' % (inet_addr, mask)
```