# Fastest way to get network/mask in Python?

Tags: python, linux

I'm looking for a way to get output like "192.168.1.0/24".

I know I can get my IP address by

```
my_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

but that's not the thing I want.
I should also mention that I'm using Linux

Comment: Are you looking for the subnet for your network adapter?  Or do you want a way to convert a mask to the bit count notation?

Comment: I'm looking for both network and a subnet mask, ideally in a notation shown above

Comment: `cat /proc/net/fib_trie` has the information you want.  It's also in the `ip address` output.

Comment: okay but how do I extract the info from there? I don't think it is tied to a specific line

Comment: tink: I don't need my IP address, I need a network I'm connected to, plus subnet mask

Comment: Of course it is tied to a specific line.  The IP and subnet are part of the configuration of a network adapter, usually assigned by DHCP.  The subnet mask just tells it how to reach the router.  You can have several adapters, and a single adapter can have several address assignments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66534468/1394729 - shows how to get the netmask. Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867435/get-subnet-from-ip-address for the network

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a soulution

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct
import ipaddress

iface = "enp0s3"
subnet_mask = socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM), 35099, struct.pack(b'256s', iface.encode()))[20:24])
my_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(my_ip+"/"+subnet_mask, strict=False)
print(network)
```

prints 192.168.1.0/24